# jquery datepicker

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I`m using datepicker with month and year drop downs.

I would like to hide displayed days. How can I do this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use css to make the class 'ui-datepicker-calendar' invisible, but I don't know if the result is an appealing visual experience.

On the other hand, a datepicker without a day picker is really just two drop-downs, so it seems to be a lot easier to display two drop downs and don't use the datepicker altogether.